# Browser wallet BTC enabled

Tags: wallet

The Metamask extension enables the user to send and receive funds (ETH, ERC20s) to external addresses, and thus it is very easy to integrate in current dapps thanks to web3 injection.

Are there any similar solutions that also allow trading of non-ethereum tokens? In particular, I would be interested in integrating a BTC-wallet into an existing dapp, already connected with Metamask, to allow the user to send/receive BTCs to the platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LN node for registration/login and has a browser add-on/extension: https://lightningjoule.com/

LNURL can be used to make browser extension/add-on that allows you to transact, register/login etc. : https://github.com/fiatjaf/awesome-lnurl

Liquality atomic swaps tool has a browser extension : https://liquality.io/atomic-swap-wallet.html

Maybe other bitcoin projects and hardware wallets have their own browser extensions as well. You will have to check particular project for it and if it doesn't exist, it can always be created considering it's open source and people can contribute if they think something useful is missing.

Maybe there are other applications/wallets that have browser extensions although ***I don't consider using a browser extension secure for anything related to bitcoin. Standalone desktop/mobile apps should be considered more secure IMO**.*

You can also check below question which has an idea and few doubts/questions involved. Unfortunately no answers.

[Can we use lnurl-auth to create a better password manager?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99584/can-we-use-lnurl-auth-to-create-a-better-password-manager)